# How to pass parameter(indexVar of iteration) from lightning component to javascript controller?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have a requirement to pass parameter(indexVar of iteration) from lightning component to javascript controller.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.productListWrapper}" var="pro" indexVar="index">
    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectedproductWrapper" class="select-options inline" change="{!c.priceListChange}" value="{!v.priceListValue}"  >
            <aura:iteration items="{!pro.productPriceList}" var="priceList">
                <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!priceList.value}" label="{!priceList.label}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
      </ui:inputSelect>
```

I want to pass index to javascript controller when user select a value(pricelist) from input select option.

I am able to do this for  anchor  tag using data attribute but it's not working for input select.

```
 <a onclick="{!c.changePricelist" data-index="{!index}" ><u>ChangePriceList</u></a><br/>
```

Comment: can you try this below code.<aura:iteration items="{!v.productListWrapper}" var="pro" indexVar="index">
    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectedproductWrapper" class="select-options inline" change="{!c.priceListChange}" value="{!v.priceListValue}" data-selected-Index="{!index}" >
       </ui:inputSelect>
</aura:iteration>
controller logic  var target = event.target;
 var dataEle = target.getAttribute("data-selected-Index");

Comment: I tried this but it's not working.

Comment: Instead of `{!priceList.value}` you can pass the `varIndex` in the text of `inputSelectOption`, so you will have the selected var index in the `priceListValue` attribute. This is only if you don't need the text of it.

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the index or the value selected ? You can get the value using `component.find("selectedproductWrapper").get("v.value");`
If you really need the index I guess you can find the position of this value inside your list.

You can find code samples [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelect.htm?search_text=ui:inputSelect).